# DB2 replication of records across differing schemas

Tags: db2, replication, database-replication

We have 2 db2 instances, each with a DB having tables with differing sets of columns. For e.g. Table T1 has 5 columns in one DB while having 3 columns in the other DB.

We would like to replicate data from T1 from one DB to another. Whil replicating, we would additionally want to apply certain transformation so that the 5 columns in the source table can be mapped to 3 columns in the target.

SQL Server lets you modify the stored procs that insert the record in the target DB. Its called MCALL or XCALL mechanism.

Does DB2 have such a feature by which a source table having one schema can be replicated to a target table with a different schema?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

There are various replication mechanisms that you can use with DB2, all of them allow you to manipulate replicated data. You didn't mention what type of replication you are planning to use; here's an example for SQL Replication: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.sqlrepl.doc/topics/iiyrssubmanipoverview.html